# Is it possible to delay variable implement(?)/recognize(?) in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

For example:

A.php (the config file):

```
<?php
$a = array('name'=>'wine[$index][name]',
           'value'=>'wine[$index][value]'
          )
?>
```

B.php:

```
include_once(a.php)
...
//for simple
$index = 0;
$b = $a;

//actual code like
foreach($data as $index=>$value) 
  $b += $a
```

I know this example won't work, just for explaination, i wanna if it is possible (if possible, how?) to delay variable $index to take value when $b = $a ?

Comment: @Relax is $b = $a the same as $b is equal to $a or are you setting $b with the value of $a?

Comment: the latter, actual code is like foreach($data as $index=>$value) $b += $a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make "a" a function

```
 function a($index) { global $data; return $data[$index] ... }

 $b = a($index);
```